# Can’t see background in Google Drive presentation viewer

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-file-viewer

I uploaded a PowerPoint presentation to Google Drive, but the Drive viewer does not show my background picture. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the background color to transparent. When changing the background color, select "custom", which gives you the option for transparency.